# Generating a properly formatted date using php for an SQL table

Tags: php, sql, date, format

I am trying to insert a date into an SQL table using a php script. I am generating the date in php using the following code:

```
Date("l F d, Y");
```

If I set the format of the 'dat' column format in my SQL table to string the date is entered correctly however if I set the column format to date the date appears as

```
0000-00-00
```

Any help?

Comment: maybe more details would be better. how you insert the date? and how you echo it ?

Answer (score 0):

The DATE and date-related data types store date values in an internal structure.  The formatting of the date value you entered is not preserved.  When saving to a string data type, it's just a string.  No date knowledge is saved.

When you SELECT the data from a DATE column, the default format for display is `0000-00-00`.  You can format the value (technique depends on the DBMS) when you SELECT the data.